# Is XMPP peer to peer connection without server possible?

Tags: xmpp

I am using libjingle for my XMPP connection. Can I connect two XMPP clients without having server in between. If yes how can I do that if no then why it is not possible?

XMPP client1 <---------Direct Audio/Video/IM----------> XMPP client2

Comment: A Peer-to-Peer XMPP concept. This is interesting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may not be able to do this directly with libjingle, but a protocol specification exists in the form of [XEP-0174](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html).  The gist is that you publish your presence and connection information over Multicast DNS (e.g. [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29)), then connect directly when you want to chat.  Apple's [iChat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichat) 
implements essentially this approach for its peer-to-peer mode.

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC is perfect example for having peer to peer connection. The answer I was looking for two years ago.

Comment: But WebRTC is not XMPP. Could you elaborate how this answers the question?

Comment: When the question was asked I was looking for peer to peer video conferencing solution. Libjingle was recently open source that time. I thought there may be some extension (or can be written) which can provide peer to peer connectivity.

Comment: That's fine, but the answer doesn't match the question now. People come here looking for an answer to XMPP P2P, not for P2P video conferencing.

Comment: WebRTC requires a server. Not for stream itself, but to initiate the connection.