# Is there a way to use XMPP protocol to make P2P instant messaging using Pidgin client?

Tags: xmpp, p2p, instant-messaging, pidgin

I want to to use [Pidgin](https://pidgin.im/) as a instant messaging client. Then I want to make [peer-to-peer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer) connection using [XMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) protocol. I do not want to use a solution including a server.

I have try and inspect those things below:

- XMPP protocol says it is a decentralized solution for im and it needs 'servers',
- Official XMPP web site also states that there is an extention for [serverless messaging](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html), but i do not get it and how to implement it in pidgin?
- The official XMPP states there is something called [Jingle](https://xmpp.org/about/technology-overview/), and through jingle anyone can send media/files peer-to-peer. But if I didn't understand wrong as a client I still connected to a server?,
- 11 years ago this question had been asked:[Is XMPP peer to peer connection without server possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632955/is-xmpp-peer-to-peer-connection-without-server-possible) Unfortunately who asked the question was looking for something like WebRTC. Check the answers. This is not what i am looking for.
- Also there's 'ejabberd'. If you use ejabberd you still make connection to ejabberd daemon and you are not instant messaging peer-to-peer. [Host Unknown - XMPP Pidgin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490220/host-unknown-xmpp-pidgin)

So my question is simple: By using "pidgin" as a client and "xmpp" as protocol; is it possible to make peer-to-peer instant messaging? And if it is possible, how can I make it?

Thank you.